# Getting return values from constant functions with signed transactions using web3 @1.0.27

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, parity, raw-transaction

I have a setup where no accounts exist on a local node and communication with contracts is done by creating raw transactions with Web3 (signed in code and not by user or node).

On the contracts there are permissioned constant getter functions. EG

```
function getSomething() public onlyOwner constant returns(bool) {
    return something;
}
```

I understand it is easy to use `contract.methods.getSomething.call()` with Web3 but that would require an unlocked account on the local node.

It is also possible to make "calls" with `web3.eth.call(obj)` but only with raw unsigned transactions.

How would I make a call with a signed transaction?

Comment: why do you need `onlyOwner`? This is a constant function, so anyone can get the return value anyways, even if he's not the owner. It only takes a little more effort than without `onlyOwner`.

Comment: @mafrasi2 Are you sure about that? When I tried, the modifier for was observed and was unable to retrieve a value. When the modifier was removed it returned a value. What do you mean by "it takes a little more time" - what would be done to bypass permission?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Since the blockchain is public anyone can read whatever data he wants from it, including all "private" variables in your contract. It's a bit more difficult than reading public variables since the compiler generates an implicit getter function for those. For private variables you need to query the storage manually. [Here](https://medium.com/aigang-network/how-to-read-ethereum-contract-storage-44252c8af925) is a guide on how to do this. Therefore, you can emulate constant functions with an address you don't own.

Comment: Just for completeness, there is one scenario, where the modifier makes sense on a constant function: when you are ok with other *people* reading the private variable, but want to prevent other *contracts* from doing so. I'm not sure where this scenario would occur in the real world though.